# Infinite strings and infinite theorems - Is there a theory on these stuffs?

Tags: logic, soft-question, finite-automata

I can have an alphabet $\mathcal{A}$, a set of axioms $\mathcal{X}$ which are finite strings of $\mathcal{A}$ and a set of rules $\mathcal{R}$.

Every finite strings produced by applying a finite number of time the rules in $\mathcal{R}$ is a theorem.

Is there some theories that studies the axioms and the theorems are infinite strings produced by applying a finite number of time the rules in $\mathcal{R}$?

Comment: Are you looking for 'infinitary logic'?

Comment: maybe, what is this? Some references?

Comment: I don't have any handy; any I could give you would simply come from web searching.

Comment: See [Infinitary Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-infinitary/).